# How to validate given textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is textarea box and I want to validate it. I want to use required field validation. How can I do that?. I have tried validating textarea box using name and CSS class but I have failed to do so.

```
<textarea <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about begging for ASAP/urgent treatment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: i also want to check if the textarea is hidden or show

Comment: it is not getting any value when i input character on it

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle, to have a better insight

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use required=true property

```
 <textarea  required=true maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details" <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" ></textarea>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").validate({
                                rules:{
                                        textarea_name:{
                                                required:true,
                                                maxlength:50
                                                }
                                      }
                               });
                           });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: <textarea  required=true maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details" <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" ></textarea>      please check this it should work